# GNUplot: Rounding max_y and min_y values from stats output

Tags: gnuplot

I'm working on using the stats min_y and max_y values to set the yrange for a full year's data. Col 4 has the values for which the min-max are needed.

This works fine

```
set terminal unknown
plot [0:4] 'fullyear.txt'
stats 'fullyear.txt' using 0:4
```

Excerpt from stats:
    `Minimum:       0.0000 [   0]       -5.0600 [  81]`
    `Maximum:    1459.0000 [1410]       34.3900 [1050]`

Then I set the yrange:
`set yrange[STATS_min_y:STATS_max_y]`
This gives me a yrange [-5:35]

What I would like for the yrange however is this, so the two values are rounded down/up:
`set yrange[floor(STATS_min_y):ceil(STATS_max_y)]`
to give a yrange [-6:36]

However plotting my file with the ceil/floor modification of set yrange doesn't appear to work as it uses only the [-5:35] values.

Do I need to do something like this (which also doesn't appear to work)?

```
maxHigh=ceil(STATS_max_y)  
maxLow=floor(STATS_min_y)  
set yrange [maxLow:maxHigh]
```

Comment: This should work, and I have tested that it does. There must be something else you are doing wrong. Maybe if you post the full script up to the `plot` command we can identify the problem. Note that `plot [0:4] ...` does not plot column 0 vs. column 4, but plots 1 vs. 2 in the xrange from 0 to 4. I don't know if that's related to your issue.

Comment: Yes, the ceil and floor functions work, and output the -6 and 36. But then unless I'm mistaken `set yrange[floor(STATS_min_y):ceil(STATS_max_y)]` should enable me to use `print yrange` to see [-6:36], no? I cannot make that work. It throws an "unknown variable" for yrange.

Comment: @miguel That shows the ceil/floor working properly, thanks. In the meantime I realized I was confusing the yrange numbers with the tics autofreq setting. The result is that with a yrange [-6:35], the ytics autofreq display is: -5. 0, and every 5 ft. up to 35, as it should  I just need to redo my ytics setting to display the negative yrange as the bottom ytic, the 0 line, and some auto range of tics up to and including the largest positive number, which I think I can sort out. Many thanks.